# Session doesn't expire or user logged out after browser close in a Firefox pinned tab

Tags: php, session, firefox, cookies, tabs

Here is the problem

Every thing is working fine with all browsers and with Firefox unpinned tab as well
, but in case of Firefox pinned tab :
   When closing the browser and back again ,,, still logged in

I use these two lines to enforce session to expire on browser close .

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
session_set_cookie_params(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `session_destroy()` function on browser close.

logout.php

```
//This is the page that will destroy all your session, call the code on this page before the browser is closed.
<?php session_start();

session_destroy();

?>
```

mypage.php

```
<script> // use ajax call to execute the code on before unload page mypage.hp

window.onbeforeunload = function(){ //send a small ajax call to logout.php so that the session wil get destroyed 
     $.ajax({
     method:'post',
     url: 'logout.php',
     data: 'nothing'
     })
}

</script>
```

Comment: session already destroyed after browser close , but no with FF pinned tab

and how to accomplish that ,, session_destroy on browser close

Comment: did you try `session_destroy()` function on browser close?

Comment: aha ,, You mean I have to use Ajax call to this page on .. 
window.unload ?

Comment: yes like the one example i have showen you in mypage.php example.

Comment: This  doesn't work because this function do actions when the page refreshed :(